# CSS for disabled form input

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have this in my CSS file that styles input fields in a form:

```
input,textarea,input,select,input,checkbox {
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    color:#98925C;
    background-color:#000;
    border:1px solid #413E22;
}
```

When I use a `disabled` on the form though (eg the submit button when pressed), it doesn't grey out like it should.

I have this in the submit button HTML

```
onclick="this.disabled=true;this.value=' done ';this.form.submit();"
```

How can i make it so the button greys out once clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your styles are overriding the browser defaults for a disabled form element.

You need to redefine the styles by specifying `:disabled` pseudoclass in your CSS.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tk3Fx/) that shows how it works.

Answer (score 3):

It does gray out in IE. For other browsers, though, you need to specifically define your "disabled element" styles with:

```
:disabled {
    color: #6b849a;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #ffffff;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Something like that (although you may have to apply `!important` if there are cascading issues).

Answer (score 2):

```
input[disabled]{
  styles here
}
```

Comment: Ah, ok, the attribute [reflects](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/Overview.html#reflect) the property. I thought the whole form would be disabled, but then even the pseudoclass doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`:disabled` pseudoclass](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-disabled). This might not work in older browsers and will surely not work in IE, so you could also add a normal class to the form when disabling it.